# HTML DOM Drawing Transaction in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, drawing

Is there a way to encapsulate several DOM manipulating commands in a transaction so that the content would not "flicker about"? Something like this:

```
window.stopDrawing(); // start transaction
$("#news").append("<div>a new news item</div>");
// ... do something more
$("#news").css("top", "-150px");
window.startDrawing(); // stop transaction
```

Comment: Browsers (newer ones) do this already, internally, to the extent that they can. There's no explicit control however. If you post more about a particular situation you're seeing, somebody may be able to suggest an optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime you must update a large set of elements just set up a function including all the operations, call mozRequestAnimationFrame(or webkitRequestAnimationFrame), only after your function is finished executing completely it will draw your changes to the screen.

More at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame

Comment: Actually, there's a standardized version of this API called [requestAnimationFrame](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/RequestAnimationFrame/Default.html)

Comment: That function doesn't exist in firefox or chrome(I don't know about IE 9) because it is experimental, that is why I recommended using the prefixed version

Answer (score 2):

I believe browsers are redrawing the document only when the script returns to the even loop, so it won't renders anything until the end of your script.

Anyway some operations may force the browser to do some costly operations such as recomputing the dimensions of elements on the document (e.g. when retrieving the dimensions of an element after some DOM manipulations have been made). So you should do DOM manipulations off-document as much as possible.

If you have many manipulations to do on some element, it *may* be cheaper to remove it from the document tree, do your manipulations, and add it to the tree again.